# How do I plot 3 sets of data and draw the bell curve variance over each point?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have 3 sets of data. My first graph will graph all 3 of them. I then want my second graph to compute the mean of each set of Y values, draw the graph and then display a bell curve over each point that represents the variance. Here is a picture of what I want and my MWE.
[image]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=6cm,compat=1.8}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{2}{%
  \pgfmathparse{1/(#2*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((x-#1)^2)/(2*#2^2))}%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xlabel=Cost,
        ylabel=Error]
    \addplot[color=red,mark=x] coordinates {
        (2,2)
        (4,4.0)
        (6,6.3)
        (8,7.8)
        };
   \addplot[color=black,mark=x] coordinates {
        (2,1.7)
        (4,3.8)
        (6,6.0)
        (8,7.95)
    };
    \addplot[color=green,mark=x] coordinates {
        (2,2.2)
        (4,3.9)
        (6,5.7)
        (8,8.1)
    };
    
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xlabel=Cost,
        ylabel=Error Distribution]
    \addplot[color=red,mark=x] coordinates {
        (2,2)
        (4,3.9)
        (6,6.0)
        (8,7.9)
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

This approach uses `pic`s to place the gaussian bell curves at the relevant coordinates in the plot. I changed the `gauss` function a bit to make it usable in a `\draw` macro (it takes three arguments now, the first being *x*). The pic is also called `gauss` and takes two arguments, the first being *μ* and the second being *σ*.

For the following code to work, you need to set at least `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}`. For older distributions, you would need to place the `pic`s using `axis cs:` (for example: `\pic[red] at (axis cs:2,2) {gauss={0}{0.3}};`).

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=6cm, compat=newest}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{3}{%
  \pgfmathparse{1/(#3*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((#1-#2)^2)/(2*#3^2))}%
}

\tikzset{
    pics/gauss/.style 2 args={
        code={
            \draw[pic actions, rotate around={-90:(0pt,0pt)}, scale around={7.5:(0pt,0pt)}] 
                plot [domain=-1:1, samples=100, smooth] (\x*1pt,{gauss(\x,#1,#2)*1pt});
        }
    },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xlabel=Cost,
        ylabel=Error]
    \addplot[color=red, mark=x] coordinates {
        (2,2)
        (4,4.0)
        (6,6.3)
        (8,7.8)
        };
   \addplot[color=black, mark=x] coordinates {
        (2,1.7)
        (4,3.8)
        (6,6.0)
        (8,7.95)
    };
    \addplot[color=green, mark=x] coordinates {
        (2,2.2)
        (4,3.9)
        (6,5.7)
        (8,8.1)
    };
    
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xlabel=Cost,
        ylabel=Error Distribution]
    \addplot[color=red, mark=x] coordinates {
        (2,2)
        (4,3.9)
        (6,6.0)
        (8,7.9)
        };
    \pic[red] at (2,2) {gauss={0}{0.3}};
    \pic[red] at (4,3.9) {gauss={0}{0.5}};
    \pic[red] at (6,6.0) {gauss={0}{0.2}};
    \pic[red] at (8,7.9) {gauss={0}{0.4}};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]